# Can't retarget project in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I've decided to learn C++. I started by downloading VS 2015 but i can't seem to get my 'Hello world' app to work.

on a Console Application project named ConsoleApplication5 I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello world!";
return 0;
 }
```

and I get the following error when pressing F5:
"The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution"."

The problem is, when I try to retarget the solution, it seems completely useless since it does nothing:

[image]

any thoughts about that?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 V14.0.2543.01 Update 3 -  on windows 10 pro

Comment: I had the same useless dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - download and install an SDK and retarget the solution after that.

You need to have the proper SDK installed. Your solution is currently targeted to use SDK 8.1. The VS message suggests you to either install it or, ***if you want to use another, already installed SDK, retarget the solution to it***. If you don't have any SDK installed, the retargeting won't help.